# Browsing android apps databases from OS X

Tags: android, database

I'd like to brows my sqlite3 database that is embedded in my app (on a rooted device).
I succeeded into reaching my device with `adb shell`.

The problem is that, under `/data/data/com.myapp.foobar` I find only onde folder : `lib`.

How can I browse the missing `databases` folder from my computer's terminal (OS X)?

Regards

Comment: Have you created the databases by running your app?

Comment: @RaghavSood yes, the databases are created.